# Select-object in CISCO IOS

Tags: cisco

I am very new to CISCO IOS and have little to none experience. I was wondering if there is a way to run a command like `show ip interface brief` and then select exactly what you want and then redirect it through tftp. I've been able to export the output of the whole command through tftp. `show ip interface brief | redirect tftp://IPAddress/output.txt` So my question:

[image]
How can I select the bottom "loopback0" information below and redirect the output again?

I've tried redirecting the whole command and tried parsing it in powershell so I could make a csv but its way to messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used Putty with session log enabled in order to get output from Cisco devices. Or if I was on Linux, I would just pipe my ssh session output in tee.

```
ssh me@cisco | tee -a outputfile.log
```

Now if you want to only show some lines in the output of your command, there are two things you can do;

1- Use grep. Yes, Cisco IOS comes with grep and it's regex capacity.

```
sh ip interface brief | grep loopback0
```

2- Use include. It's almost the same as grep...

```
sh ip interface brief | include loopback0
```

I like include better just because the abreviated version of it is simply "**i**".

```
sh ip interface brief | i loopback0
```

I'm not entire sure if you can pipe twice like this:

```
sh ip interface brief | i loopback0 | redirect tftp://IPAddress/output.txt
```

It worth noting that there is also **begin** and **exclude** that can help you filter out results of your command.

Comment: From what I've tried so far, it seems that you cant pipe twice... How else can I get this info?

Comment: The first two lines of the answer pretty much sums it up. With logging your SSH session you will have an exact copy of whatever commands and results you will send to the cisco device with the results. If you want to use scripting, then TCL is the way to go with Cisco.